# AngularJS official websocket library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I work with client side software and have to implement websocket connection. I did it with plain javascript easily (to check server side works), but now when I tried to do this with AngularJS I found huge libraries number, and all of them looks like do the same. Here I found list http://ngmodules.org/tags/websocket , but even this looks like not full. Is it any official supported AngularJS library and good example for that? If it is not exist is there some of main stream (yes I afraid about further support), or is it usual to wire self made javaScript code with AngularJS application?

Comment: Angular is a *framework*, JavaScript is the *language* it is written in. How could code written in the same language as the framework be unusual?

Comment: I find opinion about native javaScript implementation, and it states: "really bad native api example from websocket.org" https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket/blob/master/example/index.html.
So may be you misinterpret my question or I mess somewhere. Do you have any idea about official AngularJS websocket support?

Comment: My main point is that this question is off topic, since it is a request for a library or other off site resource.